# NotifyPropertyChanged when binding to itemsource of datagrid in Silverlight RIA

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, ria

I have a textbox and a datagrid in a silverlight project. The textbox should be enabled if the item count in the datagrid is 0 or the sum of a field in the datagrids itemssource = 0.

I've bound the isEnabled value of the textbox to the datagrids ItemsSource.SourceCollection which gives me an IEnumerable. I've made a converter that converts this datamodel to bool.

When I open my silverlight page and bind the datagrid, the converter runs and everything i working as expected, but nothing happens if i change the sum field or add/delete rows in the datagrid.

I'm guessing it has something to do with notify property changes on my datamodel, but I don't know.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you bind to a sub property of an object then you need a PropertyChanged event of that specific property in order for the target to update its value.

In your example the ItemsSource needs to raise a PropertyChanged event of the property SourceCollection.

What you could do is bind to ItemsSource wich will be triggered and then in your converter use the Sourcecollection value.

eg:

```
    <sdk:DataGrid Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=dg, Path=ItemsSource.Count}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

code:

```
        _items = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>();
        _items.Add(new SomeClass() { Name = "a" });
        _items.Add(new SomeClass() { Name = "b" });
        _items.Add(new SomeClass() { Name = "c" });

        DataContext = _items;

    private void testButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _items.Add(new SomeClass(){Name = "ha"});

    }
```

Comment: Changing the binding to ItemsSouce doesn't change anything.

Comment: I edited it for you to make myself more clear.  + do not forget to use an observableCollection..

Comment: I'm using PagedCollectionViews. Could it have something to do with that?

Comment: I created a sample using Luc solution with PagedCollectionView and it worked. Have a look at http://csharprambling.wordpress.com

Answer (score 0):

I asked similar question and as Luc answered you need have INotifyPropertyChanged event implementation, if not item changes will not happen.
[How to make a cell in a datagrid readonly based the content on another cell in SL4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981291/how-to-make-a-cell-in-a-datagrid-readonly-based-the-content-on-another-cell-in-sl)

Comment: It's a RIA data model, and it enherits from "Entity" which implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Can you please put a break point in the converter and debug the code and see if the converter is called when you change the collection?